# How to parse TypoScript using the new parser in TYPO3 12+

Tags: typoscript, typo3-12.x

There seem to be no information on how to use the new `TypoScript` parser. Announcement was [made here](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.0/Breaking-97816-NewTypoScriptParserInFrontend.html) without a single explanation or example on how to use the new parser in place of the old. I have this code that I've been using single early versions and works all the way up to version 12 (with deprecation notices. Code is in the `ContentObjectPostInitHook`.

```
$typoScriptParser=new TypoScriptParser();
$typoScriptParser->parse($configuration['TypoScript']);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['lib.']['menux']=$typoScriptParser->setup;

$setup=typoScriptParser->getVal($configuration['TypoScriptObjPath'], $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup);
```

The `TypoScriptParser` class has now been marked for deprecation in version 13. `TypoScriptFrontendController` class' `tmpl` property has also been deprecated. We are advised to use the new parser. How do I refactor this code to the new standard? Thank you.